# Firefox: White lines when rotating borders

Tags: html, css, firefox

I have a little problem when I rotate the borders of an `::after`: In the corner the of borders I see white lines. Here is my HTML:

```
<a class="tt__list__tabs__singleTab__backLink tt__list__tabs__wrap__links tt__list__tabs--innerTab__link" href="#tt__list__tabs__wrap--outerTabs" style="display: flex;">
    <span class="tt__list__singleTab__headline">Back</span>
 </a>
```

And here my CSS:

```
.tt__list__tabs__wrap__links{
    background:transparent;
 }

.tt__list__tabs__wrap__links::after {
    background:transparent;
    border-top: 5px solid black;
    border-right: 5px solid black;
    content: '';
    display: inline-block;
    height: 0.75em;
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    width: 0.75em;
}
```

[Here is the jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hy7vhprf/1/) for the output.

I'm using Win10, Browser is latest Firefox. Picture: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZePMf.jpg

I already tried the trick with the transparent background. Am I missing something? Any ideas?

Comment: white lines where ??? add some screenshots ?

Comment: I'm not seeing any white lines.  Can you take a screenshot?  What OS and Browser (including version numbers) are you experiencing the issue on?

Comment: I added more details and a pic. Thank you guys.

Comment: Can replicate in firefox on win10 but not in chrome on same win10 machine, would indicate it is a firefox spefic issue

Comment: I also checked Opera, Edge and IE11, works fine. Maybe any specific -moz property that could help?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found the answer for the Firefox bug:

```
transform: translateZ(1px) rotate(45deg);
```

No white lines anymore.

Updated jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/hy7vhprf/2/